# WinForms StatusStrip Label and Progress Bar Not Visible When Spring is Set

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a .Net 3.5 Winforms application that has a status strip at the bottom.  The status strip contains two labels and a progress bar with the spring property set to true, the status strip layout is set to Table.  But they are not showing up on Server 2008, but works fine on Server 2003, XP and Vista.

Has anyone come across this?  I can see anything on Google so maybe it's just me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which controls are missing? All of them? Or just the ToolStripProgressBar (which I think is the only one you set to "Spring") ?

Comment: I set them to all spring and they are all missing.

Comment: Check this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/60f67272-e9dc-47d1-80a9-9921631cbecb